# Why staking bond_extra tranaction is successful, but the value is 0,?

Tags: staking

I send a staking bond_extra tranaction and max_additional is 2000000000000,
send status is successful, but the value is 0, like:https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/0x804f40765b09361f0ce8380a2dc6a70c3e2a22cefa7da2c07742103c48322de8

Answer (score 1):

You called `bond_extra` with `0`, as evident from the call data:

```json
[
  {
    name: "max_additional",
    type: "compact<U128>",
    type_name: "BalanceOf",
    value: "0"
  }
]
```

Obviously nothing will happen. You then afterwards called it with [non zero](https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/12886574-2):

```json
[
  {
    name: "max_additional",
    type: "compact<U128>",
    type_name: "BalanceOf",
    value: "100000000000"
  }
]
```

So this should be solved?!

Comment: i use the maxAdditional  which is solving the problem ,

Comment: Then please mark the question as solved.